# Why Reader implemented based ReaderT?

Tags: haskell

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.0.2/docs/src/Control.Monad.Trans.Reader.html#ReaderT

I found that `Reader` is implemented based on `ReaderT` using `Identity`. Why don't make `Reader` first and then make `ReaderT`? Is there specific reason to implement that way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They are the same data type to share as much code as possible between `Reader` and `ReaderT`. As it stands, only `runReader`, `mapReader`, and `withReader` have any special cases. And `withReader` doesn't have any unique code, it's just a type specialization, so only two functions actually do anything special for `Reader` as opposed to `ReaderT`.

You might look at the module exports and think that isn't buying much, but it actually is. There are a lot of instances defined for `ReaderT` that `Reader` automatically has as well, because it's the same type. So it's actually a fair bit less code to have only one underlying type for the two.

Given that, your question boils down to asking why `Reader` is implemented on top of `ReaderT`, and not the other way around. And for that, well, it's just the only way that works.

Let's try to go the other direction and see what goes wrong.

```
newtype Reader r a = Reader (r -> a)
type ReaderT r m a = Reader r (m a)
```

Yep, ok. Inline the alias and strip out the newtype wrapping and `ReaderT r m a` is equivalent to `r -> m a`, as it should be. Now let's move forward to the `Functor` instance:

```
instance Functor (Reader r) where
    fmap f (Reader g) = Reader (f . g)
```

Yep, it's the only possible instance for `Functor` for that definition of `Reader`. And since `ReaderT` is the same underlying type, it also provides an instance of `Functor` for `ReaderT`. Except something has gone horribly wrong. If you fix the second argument and result types to be what you'd expect, `fmap` specializes to the type `(m a -> m b) -> ReaderT r m a -> ReaderT r m b`. That's not right at all. `fmap`'s first argument should have the type `(a -> b)`. That `m` on both sides is definitely not supposed to be there.

But it's just what happens when you try to implement `ReaderT` in terms of `Reader`, instead of the other way around. In order to share code for `Functor` (and a lot more) between the two types, the last type variable in each has to be the same thing in the underlying type. And that's just not possible when basing `ReaderT` on `Reader`. It has to introduce an extra type variable, and the only way to do it while getting the right result from doing all the substitutions is by making the `a` in `Reader r a` refer to something different than the `a` in `ReaderT r m a`. And that turns out to be incompatible with sharing higher-kinded instances like `Functor` between the two types.

Amusingly, you sort of picked the best possible case with `Reader` in that it's possible to get the types to line up right at all. Things fail a lot faster if you try to base `StateT` on `State`, for instance. There's no way to even write a type alias that will add the `m` parameter and expand to the right thing for that pair. `Reader` requires you to explore further before things break down.

Comment: `derivingVia` makes it really easy to write `newtype Reader e a = Reader e a` and pull instances from `ReaderT`. Of course, that's quite new.